# nyc and mocha code coverage failing when running in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mocha.js, code-coverage, nyc

I'm trying to generate the code coverage report for our builds in Jenkins - 
Locally when I execute the command

```
npm run coverage
```

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env mocha test -t 5000 --recursive --exit --reporter mochawesome",
    "coverage":"nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/mocha test -t 5000 --recursive --exit"
  },
```

it will run the tests and then give me the code coverage results

[image]

Now when the same code runs in jenkins I get this error

> /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api-ci-develop/workspace/back-end/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js:63
>     path = ('^' + path + (strict ? '' : path[path.length - 1] === '/' ? '?' : '/?'))
>                                                ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at pathtoRegexp (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api-ci-develop/workspace/back-end/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js:63:49)
>       at new Layer (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api-ci-develop/workspace/back-end/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:45:17)

apparently is doing something with the node_module folder and I'm not sure how to avoid that. I exclude the folder and files in the nyc config

```
  "nyc": {
    "branches": 5,
    "lines": 25,
    "functions": 13,
    "statements": 25,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "exclude": [
      "**/services/plaidService.js",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/node_modules/plaid/lib/PlaidClient.js"
    ]
  },
```

Any ideas what should I do to avoid the node_modules folder to be checked?